# How to completely remove a driver from disk and registry?

Tags: windows-7, windows, uninstall, drivers

I'm having some issues with an HP driver installation on a Windows 7 machine, probably because the driver was once installed and has not been deleted properly. The installer no longer works and aborts with an error message. One week ago it worked perfectly then after uninstalling the driver it no longer works. Windows Update does not know the HP M2727nf.

Now I wanted to know if there are some tools you could recommend in order to remove everything that is left from the uninstallation. I also read in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/379478/how-do-i-completely-remove-all-driver-data-from-a-bad-driver-in-windows-7) question, that this could be difficult.

But does anyone now good tools that do the job? I'm sure there are a few and I already found some but not really satisfied with them and most are not for Windows 7.

Comment: Search for the filename and delete the registry entry.  I would also contact HP for assistance.

Comment: pnputil -d driver.inf will remove it at least from windows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you better download the driver first. Then you can re-install the driver, after that you can safely uninstall the driver.

If it shows "The device could not start." or "One of the filter drivers for this device is invalid.", you can trick it by deleting the `UpperFilter` and `LowerFilter` registry entries.